# Subset data frame using string objects for variable, operator, and value

Tags: r, variables, char, subset

I am taking rules from a decision tree, and have the following text:

```
dev_amount_720 <= 2212
dev_orders_1440 <= 81
dev_orders_5760 > 55
dev_amount_5760 > 1649
```

What I need to do is filter my data set by these values and do counts. For example, I want to somehow turn it into this call:

```
data[which(data$dev_amount_720 <= 2212 &
           data$dev_orders_1440 <= 81 &
           data$dev_orders_5760 > 55 &
           data$dev_amount_5760 > 1649),]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? Best I have come up with is to split the string:

```
> strsplit(rule_split[1], " ")[[1]]
[1] "dev_amount_720" "<="             "2212"
```

Which allows me to subset data the following way:

```
data[which(data[<var>] <operator> <value>), ]
data[which(data["dev_amount_720"] <= 2212), ]
```

However, this is not very efficient as there are hundred of rules I need to apply this procedure to.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach. I assume you're using `strsplit` on your vector of rules, not one at a time, right? You could fancy it up a bit---presumably you only have two operators, `<=` and `>`, so you don't actually need to parse and eval the operators, you just need to check which it is and use a `switch` statement.

Comment: If you mention where you're getting the decision tree (especially if it's created in R) there might be built-in methods to count the number of rows at each split... but I'm not really sure.

Comment: When you talk about "efficiency", do you mean computational time? If so, profile your code to see where the slow parts are.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. It's coming from the C5.0 package, and as far as I can tell there is no easy way to pull out and apply the individual rules. Could be wrong. By efficiency I just mean avoid using a loop (loop through each "piece" of the rule).. maybe not a great choice of wording :)

Comment: I've essentially solved it with the loop method right now. Evaluate each piece of the rule using `do.call(operator, list(data[,variable], value)`, then check for cases where all are TRUE. It works well enough. I'll wait a bit before posting it as a potential solution.

Comment: I would suggest posting it in your question and being more specific about what improvements you're looking for. Also making your question reproducible with a little sample data would encourage answers. Make sure there are some `NA` values if that's realistic, and be specific about what to do in that case.